# Loading data from a file in GCS to GCP firestore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have written a script which loops through each record in the file and does write to the firestore collection.

Firestore Schema {COLLECTION.DOCUMENT.SUBCOLLECTION.DOCUMENT.SUBCOLLECTION}

```
     '{"KEY":"1234","DATE":"2022-10-10","SUB_COLLECTION":{"KEY":1234,"SUB_DOC":{"KEY1" : :"VAL1"}}'
     '{"KEY":"1235","DATE":"2022-10-10","SUB_COLLECTION":{"KEY":1235,"SUB_DOC":{"KEY1" : :"VAL1"}}'
     '{"KEY":"1236","DATE":"2022-10-10","SUB_COLLECTION":{"KEY":1236,"SUB_DOC":{"KEY1" : :"VAL1"}}'
...
```

##### File is read in the below line

```
read_file = filename.download_as_string()
```

##### converted to a list of strings

```
    fire_client = firestore.Client(project=PROJECT)
    dict_str = read_file.decode("UTF-8");
    dict_str = dict_str.split('\n');
    dict_str = dict_str.split('\n');
        for i in range(0,len(dict_str)-1):
         i = json.loads(dict_str[i])
         doc_ref = fire_client.collection('STATIC_COLLECTION_NAME').document(i['KEY'])
         doc_ref.set({"KEY" : int(i['KEY']), "DATE" : i['DATE']})
         sub_ref = doc_ref.collection('STATIC_SUB_COLLECTION_NAME').document('STATIC_SUB_DOC_NAME')
         sub_ref.set(i['SUB_COLLECTION'])
```

However, this job is consuming hours to complete a file size of 100 MB. Is there a way I could do this using multiple writes at a time, example batch processing of X number of records from the file and write those to X documents and sub-collections in the firestore.
Finding a way to make this more efficient instead of looping over millions of records, my current script ended up with
503 The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [bulk_writer](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/client#bulkwriteroptions-optionalgooglecloudfirestorev1bulkwriterbulkwriteroptions--none) to accumulate & send writes to Firestore